# -ing nouns and verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects, coordinating-conjunctions, ing

I have the sentence "It seems that stealing and selling pedigree pets # a lucrative and worthwhile business." and my question is, if I should put "is" or "are" as a verb?

Comment: The sentence structure is *X and Y # Z* where # represents the copula. There is a reasoned answer at the other question. However, if something still is not clear, edit this question to explain what that is.

Comment: Actually, I don't find those explanations very helpful. We have there a typical principle of proximity and the number of second conjoin determines the form of the verb. So please, tell me if I should use "is" or "are" in my sentence.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain how the other answer cannot be applied to it. Perhaps you're thinking that "stealing and selling" is a single operation?

Comment: Yes, I treat "stealing and selling" as a single operation and subject at the same time.

Comment: Since you treat "stealing and selling" as a single operation (and more tellingly, as a single ***subject***), why would you consider the possibility of using a plural verb form?

Comment: Ok. I'll use "is" then. Thank you.